# Proving $(a)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p ∈ \mathbb{N}$ be a prime and let $(p)$ be the principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $p$. Prove that $(p)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

You may assume that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain.

So $(p)=\{zp \, | \, z\in \mathbb{Z} \}$. I was trying to do it by contradiction. Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose for any $J$, which is an ideal of $R$ with $(p) \subset J$, we have $J \neq R$. So $(p) \subset J \subset R$.

What next? If there is an easier approach, please say.

Comment: Use the following: $(p)\subset (q)$ if and only if $q$ divides $p$.

Comment: Did you change between $(p)$ and $(a)$?

Comment: sorry that was typo, fixxed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $J$ contains $p$ and some number $q$ which is not a multiple of $p$.  Then $\gcd(p,q)=1$, so for some $m,n$ we have $mp+nq=1 \in J$.  Thus $J=R$.

Comment: what does gcd mean? Ive only heard of hcf. is it greates common divisor?

Comment: @snowman Yes, they're the same.

Comment: I don't get how it came to J=R. I understand everything before that bit.

Comment: If $J$ contains 1, then it contains every multiple of $1$ since it's an ideal.

Answer (score 0):

By contrary assume that there is a maximal ideal M between (p) and Z. Let m is an element of M that is not in (p). Then ideal M contains Zp and r, with 0 < r< p. As (p,r)=1, then pt+rs=1, for some  t,s belong to Z. Thus M contains 1 and so Z=M, a contradiction.